# Declaring Instance of Class without Instantiation & Initialization - Clarification

Tags: java, swing, class, object, jpanel

I am working on lessons that work with Java Swing, but I have run into a hurdle. In this project, we are working on setting size for different components, however, the instructor specifically typed a line of code I did not particularly understand, and I am just looking for an explanation of the concept for this line of code.

Basically, I know how to create an object of a class. Let's say we wanted a new scanner class. Creating an object for the Scanner class is simple, and appears to look like the following:

```
public class ScannerProgram {

import java.util.Scanner; //Imports Scanner Class

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
// ^ Creates object of the Scanner Type, and calls the "Scanner" constructor.
}

}
```

In one of the lessons I am watching, the instructor is creating a customized component using a user-created class that extends JPanel, and we are looking to get the preferred size. The instructor does it this way:

```
import java.awt.Dimension; //Imports Dimension class
import javax.swing.JPanel; //Imports JPanel class


public class FormPanel extends JPanel {

    public FormPanel() {

        Dimension dim = getPreferredSize(); //Question 1
        System.out.println(dim); //Prints results
        //The result is java.awt.Dimension[width=10,height=10]


    }
}
```

**Question 1:** I would like to know exactly what this line of code is doing. I know that you are declaring a variable of the "Dimension" type, but after that it becomes confusing because you are not calling a constructor. In this scenario, the variable is being set equal to "getPreferredSize()," and I am not particularly sure what it is doing. Is it calling a specific method from the Dimension class? That is my guess, but I actually am not sure at all. Thanks to anybody willing to shed light on this.

Also, feel free to change the title if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getPreferredSize()` is a method of `JPanel` (or of a super-class of `JPanel`) that returns a `Dimension` instance. `getPreferredSize()` is called on the instance being constructed by the `FormPanel` constructor.

Comment: Thank you, and I found this to be extremely helpful!
I even researched, and found out how it returns a Dimension in the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize(java.awt.Dimension)